# Sql Trigger on a view does not getting triggered

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a view getting data from others views when data is inserted in this specific view as show bellow need to insert in table vendas ref(nvarchar(50)) and Estado(bool).

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_VENDAS] 
ON [dbo].[VendasFinal]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @Ref  nvarchar(50),
@EstadoString nvarchar(50)

SELECT @Ref = i.ref, @EstadoString = i.ESTADO 
FROM inserted i

if(@EstadoString = 'Em Aberto')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Vendas
            (ref, Estado)
        VALUES
            (@Ref ,0);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Vendas
            (ref, Estado)
        VALUES
            (@Ref ,1);
    END
END
```

It's running on a MS Sql Server 11.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per *row*. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. That's the first obvious issue with this trigger. However, you've not stated whether you're getting an error or how else you've determined that the trigger "does not get triggered" so further help is difficult to provide.

Comment: what mean fire per statement? I just edit the question.

Comment: It means that `inserted` table contains **all** the rows that were inserted. It's not one row at the time thing.

Comment: temporary change this code "SELECT (at)Ref = i.ref, (at)EstadoString = i.ESTADO 
FROM inserted i" to "SELECT @Ref = convert(nvarchar(50), count(*)) 
FROM inserted i" and you'll see how a trigger is SET BASED

Comment: Can i run a cursor on inserted table?

Comment: You could run a cursor but why? This is nothing more than a single set based insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor here. You just need to use a case expression. Your posted trigger can be simplified to this. It handles any number of rows and the logic you have in the existing code.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_VENDAS] 
ON [dbo].[VendasFinal]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO dbo.Vendas
    (
        ref
        , Estado
    )
    SELECT i.ref
        , case when i.ESTADO = 'Em Aberto' then 0 else 1 end
    from inserted i
```